# How can I change the placeholder color from my el-input with Element UI

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

Im using vue.js and element ui. Im trying to change the placeholder color but i dont know how to do that.

Already tried this but not working:

```
.el-input__inner::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999999;
   font-size: 16px;
}

.el-input__inner:-moz-placeholder {
   color: #999999;
   font-size: 16px;
}

.el-input__inner:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Since you're using a component library which likely contains css you could try adding important `color: #999999 !important;`

Comment: I tried and doesnt work :/

Comment: your selector is not correct. take a look at the selector again and use !important

Comment: @Mojtaba yoo man I was calling wrong the el-input its working now thanks man :)

Comment: Do it as an answer to make it the right one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your selector is not correct. take a look at the selector again and use !important

Answer (score 0):

```
.el-input__inner::placeholder {
  color:  #31E5F5;
}
/* google */
.el-input__inner::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color:  #31E5F5;
}
/* firefox */
.el-input__inner:-moz-placeholder {
  color:  #31E5F5;
}
/*ie*/
.el-input__inner:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color:  #31E5F5;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).